# firestore get five docs with more sub collections quantity

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have a collection called courses with a sub collection called students. I want to get the five courses collections with the most students sub collections quantity.
my code:

```
await app.firestore()
        .collection('courses')
        .orderBy('students', 'desc')
        .limit(5)
        .get()
        .then(query => {
            let recommendedCourses = [];
            query.forEach(doc => {
                recommendedCourses.push({id: doc.id, ...doc.data()})
            });
            dispatch(setRecommendedCourses(recommendedCourses))
        }).catch(error => console.log(JSON.stringify(error)));
```

So my query should go through all the courses and count there students subcollections to get the five courses collections with the more students sub collections

Comment: What's the problem with the code?  If it isn't working the way you expect, please edit the question with your observations, and how they're different than your expectations.

Comment: I think this part of the query is not the correct way to do the filtering ".orderBy('students.length', 'desc')" and thats why It does not return the courses with the highest amount of students

Comment: Since we can't see the data you're working with, it's not possible to tell.  Please edit the question to illustrate what's not working with the actual data you're querying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no built-in way to filter the documents in your `courses` collection based on properties in their `students` subcollections. A query in Firestore can only filter on properties of the collection that it returns documents from.

So to allow querying on the number of students of a course, you will have to add a `studentCount` field to each course document. You'd update this field from your code whenever you add/remove a student, with the `FieldValue.increment()` function.

Once you have that you will be able to get the courses with the most student by filtering on the field you created, similar to the code you already have.